# Creating an object from a type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, factory

I want to create a method that takes a type parameter, obviously with no parameters on its constructor, and returns a dummy object constructed with that constructor. Basically some kind of factory pattern.

- Is that even possible in Scala?
- Is that a good idea? Any better pattern if it is not?
- Is there a way to achieve this at compile-time only (i.e. without reflection)?

Code example :

```
trait Model
class A extends Model
class B extends Model

def dummy[T <: Model] = new T   // Fails compilation with "class type required but T found"

dummy[A]  // Returns an instance of A
dummy[B]  // Returns an instance of B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using `ClassManifest`s, which are designed to overcome erasure:

```
def dummy[T <: Model : ClassManifest] = classManifest[T].erasure.newInstance
```

As for doing it at compile time without reflection, I guess that it could be done using scala 2.10 macros.

Comment: Do you need to load the `scala-reflect` JAR to use class manifests? On Android, Scala reflection doesn't work really well at the moment, which is why I'd like to avoid using it...

Comment: No, you don't need the `scala-reflect` JAR just to use manifests.

Comment: Hm, I'm getting "Not found: Type /" when trying this out... Which version of Scala do you use?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo (don't know how it got there as I have tested it in the REPL). The '/' was supposed to be a ':'.

Comment: Note that in Scala 2.10.x `ClassManifest` is deprecated and is just a type alias for `scala.reflect.ClassTag`, so it might be better just using it directly. `classManifest[T].erasure` is now `implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass`.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanations. I'm still having a little bit of trouble figuring out the intricacies of the type system -- reflection  isn't exactly straightforward, but this helps!